# Is there any advantage of $1$ over 1?

Tags: math-mode

Sometimes, I often write numbers in LATEX as `$69$` or so. Some other times, I write it plainly as `69`. Is there any advantage of one over the other?

Comment: If the fonts are the same, there may appear no difference, outside of some kerning issues.  However, if math font differs from the text font, you need to give careful consideration on whether the subject number is a mathematical or textual expression.  They will certainly present differently in appearance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Segletes says in a comment, it will often make no perceptible difference.  But if you are writing for publication, then the publisher may use one font for numerals in text and a different one for numerals in math expressions.  Then to make up an example you might write `add 3 to get $x+3$` and the 3's will not match in the printed version, and it does not show up until you see page proofs and you must search to find all the problems.  Since this has happened to me I always decide whether each number is meant as mathematical or just textual and mark it accordingly in the first place.